# How to arrange decimal values one by one from right side to left side

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I design setting for amount section so my requirements are: 1. the default Amount shall be $0.00. and 2. the max amount shall be $99999.99 and 3. when an amount is entered using the numerical keyboard,the amount shall get populated from right side of the decimal point (cents) to the left side of decimal point(Dollar). For e.g default value is $0.00 and when i put 1 then it should show $0.01 And when i put 2 it should show $0.12 and after that For 3 it should show $1.23 and so on to $99999.99.
I am not sure but i think this method should used

`-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

OR

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField.`

I am little bit weak in coding if possible please give me answer in code that would be better for me.

How can i get this? Need help.

Thanks

Comment: Are u doing smethng lik a calculator ?

Comment: Where you will put? where you have to show? Means, do you have one text field and one label?

Comment: i have only one text field and i am doing it for Amount field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)btnPointPress:(id)sender
{

if([stringMain length] < 10)
{
      stringMain = [[NSString stringWithFormat:stringMain]stringByAppendingFormat:@"."];
        pointCheck = YES;
        pointOnce++;

}

lastString = stringMain;
number = [stringMain doubleValue];
}
```

This is for adding a decimal point. Now tell me after this what is your requirement ?

Comment: @ Gill: thanks. Actually i want to show it in a text field for Iphone Application when user insert number they arrange in required format.

Comment: I dont think you can arrange the data on run time ... I think you will be able to do it on some action like that of a button ....

Comment: @ Gill : Its a text field not button.

Comment: I knw so do u want to change the data on the tap of the textfield like on -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField or on - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField ??

Comment: @ Gill:Yes, Now you understand what i was trying to say. help me

Comment: In that case take 2 strings .... one will keep the previous value and the other the value the user entered... Then append both the strings to give the result ... u got the general idea ??

Comment: @ Gill: But how can i set the decimal point and how can i arrange the strings so i would get output in required format.

Comment: @ Gill: In which Delegate should i start to write the code. please give me information in detail. Thanks

Comment: textfield.text = [[string1 stringByAppendingString:@"  "] stringByAppendingString:textString];

Comment: @-Gill: how can i set the decimal point for two points? and tell me in which delegate should i start to Edit?

Comment: U can also do it on -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: @ Gill: i set decimal for 2 points because its requirement( e.g 2.22  , 3333.33 like that only for two point). now tell me please how to do it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286916/nsstring-validation check this link.... and this 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295179/adding-a-decimal-point-button-to-an-ios-calculator

Comment: And how to push the number from right side to left side with two decimal digits.

Comment: seems interesting but how to use UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft in my code so that i get my required output with TWO DECIMAL DIGIT???????

Comment: oh! please i am now totally frustrated if possible then please give me whole code . i think its 10 to 20 lines code so please send me it would be better for me.Thanks

Comment: @ Gill :And you are awesome man you have lot of knowledge its nice to meet you man.

Comment: Thanks @AG29 ill make the code and if possible send it to u by today :)... But Please mail me your whole requirement so that I can compose the simplest solution... meanwhile try on ur own ....

Comment: @ Gill: I design setting for amount section so my requirements are: 1. the default Amount shall be $0.00. and 2. the max amount shall be $99999.99 and 3. when an amount is entered using the numerical keyboard,the amount shall get populated from right side of the decimal point (cents) to the left side of decimal point(Dollar). For e.g default value is $0.00 and when i put 1 then it should show $0.01 And when i put 2 it should show $0.12 and after that For 3 it should show $1.23 and so on to $99999.99. Please send the code me on  ashishgore29@gmail.com. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: @Gill-: did u send me the  solution i am still waiting.

Comment: @Gill-: i got the answer gill.