# Character occurrences in a String Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

How can I count the occurrence of a character in a string?

*Example*

*String: 123-456-7890*

*I want to find the occurrence count of "-" in given string*

Comment: Repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938095/nsstring-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of Occurrences of a Character in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938095/number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-nsstring)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
NSString *string = @"123-456-7890";
int times = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count]-1;

NSLog(@"Counted times: %i", times);
```

**Output:**

`Counted times: 2`

Comment: Its also best code to find how many SPACES occurred in string. . .

Comment: What if the string starts with '-'?

Comment: @Oscar It will still work, I just tested it. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @hfossli, you're wrong, it will return 4 and 2 respectively.

Comment: @Cœur you are absolutely right! Crazy in my opinion. https://gist.github.com/hfossli/4c76a96b34574cb938ce

Comment: Yup, this won't work accurately if the sub-string is at the end. Use the following replacement string, which returns the count of replacements. Easy peasy, and accurate.
- (NSUInteger)replaceOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options range:(NSRange)searchRange;

Comment: Will this end up allocating a lot of new NSString instances into memory -- the split substrings that are being counted -- when the search string is large?

Answer (score 2):

This will do the work,

```
int numberOfOccurences = [[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count];
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this for you. try this.

```
unichar findC;
int count = 0;
NSString *strr = @"123-456-7890";

for (int i = 0; i<strr.length; i++) {
    findC = [strr characterAtIndex:i];
    if (findC == '-'){
        count++;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%d",count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = [[[myString mutableCopy] autorelease] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"X" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
```

The `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` method returns the number of replacements that were made, so we can use that to work out how many `-`s are in your string.

Comment: Doesn't that cause a memory leak as you aren't releasing the copy?

Comment: @trojanfoe You have to release the copy of course, but it's out of the scope of the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's also not possible with this code as you don't have a pointer to the copy.  It is out-of-scope, yes, but many newbies are likely to copy this code verbatim and then wonder why they are leaking memory.

Comment: That's true, if you're doing manual memory management then `autorelease` is required. I've been using ARC for so long that I forget not everyone is!

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 0;
NSString *str = @"123-456-7890";
for(int i=0; i<[str length];i++)
{
    unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
    if (![[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c])
    {
        NSLog(@"%c",c);
        total++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%d",total);
```

this worked. hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` method of `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

The current selected answer will fail if the string starts or ends with the character you are checking for.

Use this instead:

```
int numberOfOccurances = (int)yourString.length - (int)[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""].length;
```