# Number of occurrences of substring in string in Swift

Tags: regex, swift

My main string is "hello Swift Swift and Swift" and substring is Swift.
I need to get the number of times the substring "Swift" occurs in the mentioned string.

This code can determine whether the pattern exists.

```
var string = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"

if string.rangeOfString("Swift") != nil {
    println("exists")
}
```

Now I need to know the number of occurrence.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

A simple approach would be to split on `"Swift"`, and subtract 1 from the number of parts:

```
let s = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
let tok =  s.components(separatedBy:"Swift")
print(tok.count-1)
```

This code prints 3.

**Edit:** Before [Swift 3 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38358312/335858) the code looked like this:

```
let tok =  s.componentsSeparatedByString("Swift")
```

Answer (score 36):

Should you want to count characters rather than substrings:

```
extension String {
    func count(of needle: Character) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) {
            $1 == needle ? $0 + 1 : $0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Swift 5 Extension

```
extension String {
    func numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: String) -> Int {
        return self.components(separatedBy:string).count - 1
    }
}
```

Example use

```
let string = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
let numberOfOccurrences = string.numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: "Swift")
        
// numberOfOccurrences = 3
```

Comment: Nice hack if you don't need case insensitive search.

Answer (score 21):

Optimising [dwsolbergs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707651/1033581) to count faster. Also faster than `componentsSeparatedByString`.

```
extension String {
    /// stringToFind must be at least 1 character.
    func countInstances(of stringToFind: String) -> Int {
        assert(!stringToFind.isEmpty)
        var count = 0
        var searchRange: Range<String.Index>?
        while let foundRange = range(of: stringToFind, options: [], range: searchRange) {
            count += 1
            searchRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: foundRange.upperBound, upper: endIndex))
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// return 2
"aaaa".countInstances(of: "aa")
```

- If you want to ignore accents, you may replace `options: []` with `options: .diacriticInsensitive` like dwsolbergs did.
- If you want to ignore case, you may replace `options: []` with `options: .caseInsensitive` like ConfusionTowers suggested.
- If you want to ignore both accents and case, you may replace `options: []` with `options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]` like ConfusionTowers suggested.
- If, on the other hand, you want the fastest comparison possible and you can guarantee some canonical form for composed character sequences, then you may consider option [`.literal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412961-literal) and it will only perform exact matchs.

Comment: A very nice solution, especially since by changing the options to `[.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]` it can find the search term without regard for upper/lower case. Bravo!

Answer (score 17):

I'd recommend an extension to string in Swift 3 such as:

```
extension String {
    func countInstances(of stringToFind: String) -> Int {
        var stringToSearch = self
        var count = 0
        while let foundRange = stringToSearch.range(of: stringToFind, options: .diacriticInsensitive) {
            stringToSearch = stringToSearch.replacingCharacters(in: foundRange, with: "")
            count += 1
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

It's a loop that finds and removes each instance of the stringToFind, incrementing the count on each go-round. Once the searchString no longer contains any stringToFind, the loop breaks and the count returns.

Note that I'm using .diacriticInsensitive so it ignore accents (for example résume and resume would both be found). You might want to add or change the options depending on the types of strings you want to find.

Comment: `replaceSubrange` may be better than `replacingCharacters` to avoid creating a new string each time. Also, using `range(of:options:range:)` may be better than `range(of:options:)` to avoid searching from the startIndex each time.

Comment: I've applied described optimisations in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45073012/1033581).

Answer (score 4):

I needed a way to count substrings that may contain the start of the next matched substring. Leveraging [dwsolbergs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546546/dwsolberg) extension and Strings range(of:options:range:locale:) method I came up with this String extension

```
extension String
{
    /**
     Counts the occurrences of a given substring by calling Strings `range(of:options:range:locale:)` method multiple times.

     - Parameter substring : The string to search for, optional for convenience

     - Parameter allowOverlap : Bool flag indicating whether the matched substrings may overlap. Count of "" in "" is 2 if allowOverlap is **false**, and 3 if it is **true**

     - Parameter options : String compare-options to use while counting

     - Parameter range : An optional range to limit the search, default is **nil**, meaning search whole string

     - Parameter locale : Locale to use while counting

     - Returns : The number of occurrences of the substring in this String
     */
    public func count(
        occurrencesOf substring: String?,
        allowOverlap: Bool = false,
        options: String.CompareOptions = [],
        range searchRange: Range<String.Index>? = nil,
        locale: Locale? = nil) -> Int
    {
        guard let substring = substring, !substring.isEmpty else { return 0 }

        var count = 0

        let searchRange = searchRange ?? startIndex..<endIndex

        var searchStartIndex = searchRange.lowerBound
        let searchEndIndex = searchRange.upperBound

        while let rangeFound = range(of: substring, options: options, range: searchStartIndex..<searchEndIndex, locale: locale)
        {
            count += 1

            if allowOverlap
            {
                searchStartIndex = index(rangeFound.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1)
            }
            else
            {
                searchStartIndex = rangeFound.upperBound
            }
        }

        return count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

why not just use some length maths??

```
extension String {
    func occurences(of search:String) -> Int {
        guard search.count > 0 else {
            preconditionFailure()
        }

        let shrunk = self.replacingOccurrences(of: search, with: "")

        return (self.count - shrunk.count)/search.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var mainString = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
var count = 0

mainString.enumerateSubstrings(in: mainString.startIndex..<mainString.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (subString, subStringRange, enclosingRange, stop) in

    if case let s? = subString{

        if s.caseInsensitiveCompare("swift") == .orderedSame{
            count += 1
        }
    }


}

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness – and because there is a `regex` tag – this is a solution with Regular Expression

```
let string = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "swift", options: .caseInsensitive)
let numberOfOccurrences = regex.numberOfMatches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
```

The option `.caseInsensitive` is optional.

Comment: This fails if the original string has regex special characters but the intent is to do a plain string search.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `RegexBuilder` in `iOS 16+` & `swift 5.7+`.

```
import RegexBuilder
```

```
let text  = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
let match = text.matches(of: Regex{"Swift"})
print(match.count) // prints 3
```

**Using this as a function**

```
func countSubstrings(string : String, subString : String)-> Int{
    return string.matches(of: Regex{subString}).count
}

print(countSubstrings(string: text, subString: "Swift")) //prints 3
```

**Using this as an Extension**

```
extension String {
    
    func countSubstrings(subString : String)-> Int{
        return self.matches(of: Regex{subString}).count
    }
}

print(text.countSubstrings(subString: "Swift")) // prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, maybe it will be better to use `String.Index` instead of `Int` range but I think in such way it is a bit easier to read.

```
extension String {
    func count(of char: Character, range: (Int, Int)? = nil) -> Int {
        let range = range ?? (0, self.count)

        return self.enumerated().reduce(0) {
            guard ($1.0 >= range.0) && ($1.0 < range.1) else { return $0 }
            return ($1.1 == char) ? $0 + 1 : $0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this function, can you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

Solution which uses a higher order functions

```
func subStringCount(str: String, substr: String) -> Int {
    { $0.isEmpty ? 0 : $0.count - 1 } ( str.components(separatedBy: substr))
}
```

---

Unit Tests

```
import XCTest

    class HigherOrderFunctions: XCTestCase {

        func testSubstringWhichIsPresentInString() {
            XCTAssertEqual(subStringCount(str: "hello Swift Swift and Swift", substr: "Swift"), 3)
        }

        func testSubstringWhichIsNotPresentInString() {
            XCTAssertEqual(subStringCount(str: "hello", substr: "Swift"), 0)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift's `Collection` now [has](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/ranges(of:)) a `ranges(of:)` which you can also use.

```swift
let string = "hello Swift Swift and Swift"
string.ranges(of: "Swift").count // 3
```