# componentsSeparatedByString() Error in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

```
var numbers = "Hello,Goodbye,Hi,Bye"
var numbersArr = numbers.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

`//["Hello"."Goodbye","Hi","Bye"]`

Above is a basic representation of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to use `componentsSeparatedByString()` to split a string with commas into an array, where each of the components of the array are between each of the commas from the original strings.

I am using IBM Swift Sandbox (Sorry, I'm on windows :) ), and in Swift 3.0, I am getting this error message:

```
value of type 'String' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'
```

I know Swift 3 is rather new, and is that is why I couldn't find ANY other references for this error.

Comment: This question is about Cocoa Foundation, not Swift. Are you even able to access Cocoa Foundation framework on Windows?

Comment: I think it does (the IBM Swift Sandbox runs on Linux), but there is a also a "pure Swift" `split()` method which does not require Foundation, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226940/swift-version-of-componentsseparatedbystring

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It looks like there is a `components(separatedBy:)` on `String`:

```
import Foundation

let words = "apple binary cat delta echo".components(separatedBy: " ")
print(words)
```

[image]

IBM Playground link:
http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57868332b4e4e9971bf9f4e8

Comment: This method is provided by Foundation.  You need to `import Foundation` to get this capability (note that `import UIKit` and `import Cocoa` both `import Foundation` for you).

Comment: @vacawama But can he even do that on Windows? I don't think so.

Comment: He's using the IBM Sandbox.  This works there with `import Foundation`.

Comment: It works perfectly as long as foundation has been imported, even on IBM Swift Sandbox on windows. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Thanks for this fix, there's a bug in the compiler Xcode 8, beta 6 that prompts a change to `componentsSeparatedByString(by:",")` and then suggests you change it back again! So this was great to find.