# Setting the cursor position within a SwiftUI TextEditor

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, text-editor

Is there any way to programmatically move the cursor to a specific text line or select it within a SwifUI `TextEditor`?

For example, if there is a `TextEditor` with 10 lines written in it.
When the user presses a button, the cursor will navigate to, or the text will be selected on the 3rd line.

Comment: What is your definition of the text line?

Comment: Like lines of code, every text until a line break.
e.g. swift:2:1: means the line after the first line break.

Comment: Okay.  You point us to a web site and say that it's for `UITextField`.  So it this question about `NSTextField` or `NSTextView` in Cocoa or SwiftUI?

Comment: Sorry if this was misleading, the link was just to give more idea of what I meant by setting the cursor position.
But what I am asking for is to do it in the SwiftUI `TextEditor`, which is like the `NSTextView`, if that's what you meant.

I was thinking of wrapping an `NSTextView` to use in SwiftUI instead of the new `TextEditor`, but I don't know if this is the only solution.

Comment: I would remove the statement concerning `UITextField`, which is not quite relevant to your question.

Comment: Oh okay, you are right. I removed it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible using the default SwiftUI `TextEditor`. You can achieve the desired behavior by wrapping `NSTextField`(/`UITextField`) in a `NSViewRepresentable`(/`UIViewRepresentable`).

I recently implemented this for [`CodeEditor`](https://github.com/ZeeZide/CodeEditor). You can check out the implementation there (especially the [changes from my PR](https://github.com/ZeeZide/CodeEditor/pull/5/files)).

However, since you mentioned code in one of the comments, you might also just want to use `CodeEditor` as a whole.

With my implementation, you can provide the editor with a binding to a `Range<String.Index>`.

```swift
 struct ContentView: View {
    static private let initialSource = "let a = 42\n"

    @State private var source = Self.initialSource
    @State private var selection = Self.initialSource.endIndex..<Self.initialSource.endIndex

    var body: some View {
        CodeEditor(source: $source,
                   selection: $selection,
                   language: .swift,
                   theme: .ocean,
                   autoscroll: true)
        Button("Select All") {
            selection = source.startIndex..<source.endIndex
        }
    }
}
```

You can move the cursor by updating `selection`. If the range is "empty" you just move the cursor to the start index. Otherwise the characters from start (included) to end index (excluded) get selected.

The solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207611/ios-string-get-line-and-column-number-from-absolute-position-and-vice-versa) should allow you to find the right `String.Index` for the line you want to place your cursor in.

If you want to select the whole line, scan the string from this `String.Index` in both directions until you find a newline character.