# Swift count how many of same word in a string

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to be able to count how many times a word/phrase exists in a string.

I am trying:

```
 let counter =  htmlString.components(separatedBy:"href=\"/user/")
```

But it is giving me 11 when there is just 10 on the page.

I am getting them from here via the source code.
I am not using the .json way as I need to get the avatar urls etc.

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/about/moderators
```

Comment: Are you sure there are only 10 cases? One of them isn't commented out or anything?

Comment: I am getting them from: https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/about/moderators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting 11 makes sense.

Think about this example:

```swift
"ababa".components(separatedBy: "b")
```

If you split the string everywhere a "b" occurs, you'll get 3 strings that are all "a", so you have to subtract 1 to get the answer you want: 2.

This works even if there are not other characters between what you are looking for:

```swift
"bb".components(separatedBy: "b")
```

The above code returns 3 empty strings, so you cant still take the count and subtract 1 to get the number you want.

Also see similar question with relevant answers: [Number of occurrences of substring in string in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746223/number-of-occurrences-of-substring-in-string-in-swift)

Comment: Ah yes, this is called a ["fencepost error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)